# how to compare a list type of object with list type int

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to compare two lists with Linq or lambda expression. I don't want to use any kind of loops.

if I have both of the list type of integer, I would use this expression

example 1

```
List<int> tlistA = new List<int>();
tlistA.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

List<int> tlistB = new List<int>();  
tlistB.AddRange(new int[] { 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 });


     Console.WriteLine((from   tla in tlistA
                        where  tlistB.Contains(tla)
                        select tla).Any());
```

However, if I have both of the list type of object, I would use this expression

example 2

```
   class la{public int v { get; set; }}
    class lb{public int v { get; set; }}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<la> listA = new List<la>
        {
            new la() { v  =  1 },
            new la() { v  =  2 },
            new la() { v  =  3 },
            new la() { v  =  4 },
            new la() { v  =  5 },
        };
        List<lb> listB = new List<lb>
        {
            new lb() { v  =  3 },
            new lb() { v  =  5 },
            new lb() { v  =  6 },
            new lb() { v  =  7 },
            new lb() { v  =  8 },
        };


        Console.WriteLine(listB
            .Where(b =>
            listA
            .Any(a => a.v == b.v))
            .Any());
    }
```

But, my question is how I would compare a list type of integer with another list  type of object that has an integer property.

to make my question clear to understand "How I would compare tlistA from example 1 with listB from example 2?"

thanks a lot

Comment: why does it matter whether or not you use any form of a loop. It may not be reasonable to expect to be able to compare two lists without being able to enumerate each of them (which require a loop, even if it is abstracted away using `linq`).

can you also define what it means to compare two lists? what are you comparing exactly and what are you expecting as a response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient approach is not `Where` + `Contains` + `Any` but `Intersect` + `Any`:

```
bool intsContainV = tlistA.Intersect(listB.Select(b => b.v)).Any();
```

The key is that you have select the `int` property from the objects to use it in `Intersect`.

So you could also use your (slow) `Where`-`Contains`-approach:

```
bool intsContainV = tlistA
    .Where(i => listB.Select(b => b.v).Contains(i))
    .Any();
```

or shorter:

```
bool intsContainV = tlistA.Any(i => listB.Select(b => b.v).Contains(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tlistA.Where(x => listB.Select(y => y.v).Contains(x)).Any();
```

or

```
tListA.Intersect(listB.Select(y => y.v)).Any();
```

In essence you need to turn `ListB` into an integer list and that is done by
`ListB.Select(y => y.v)` once it is an integer list you can freely compare your integer lists through whatever method you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
listA.Where(lstA => listB.Any(lstB.Contains(lstA)))
```

Comment: Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!